# Node.Js removing one item from an array using the .filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of objects, I am trying to remove a specific item based on a passed argument from the user,

```js
removeItem = (title, body){

let myArray = [
  { title : 'title 1', body: 'body of title one' },
  { title : 'title 2', body: 'body of title two' },
  { title : 'title 3', body: 'body of title three' },
]

//the problem is down here
let filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => {
  item.title != title || item.body != body
}
  
// at this point i assume that the filtered array will not
// include the item that i want to remove
// so down here i reset the value of my original array to the filtered one
 
myArray = filteredArray
```

in simple words, the test that i am trying to run is, 
if either the title or the body of the user DOES NOT match a title or body in the array, put this item in a new array, therefore i will have a filtered array..

however, what happens is, the code above, removes eveything and returns an empty array.. 
could someone help correct the logic above ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: The filter function needs to return a boolean value, true if you want to "keep" it false to remove it. So your code should be `return item.title != title || item.body != body`

Comment: The code does not run

Answer (score 3):

Either add **return** statement or **remove** curly brackets from the arrow function:)

```
myArray = myArray.filter(item => {
  return item.title != title || item.body != body;
});
```

or

```
myArray = myArray.filter(item => item.title != title || item.body != body);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a `boolean` value to your filter function. Return `true` to keep the element otherwise `false`.
Currently you are returning undefined, which is false.

```js
let myArray = [
  {title : 'title 1', body: 'body of title one'},
  {title : 'title 2', body: 'body of title two'},
  {title : 'title 3', body: 'body of title three'}
]
let title = "title 1";
let body = "body of title one";


let filteredArray = myArray.filter((item) =>item.title != title || item.body != body);

 console.log(filteredArray);
```

For reference : [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2):

[From MDN Filter page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> callback
>   Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise. It accepts three arguments:

Your callback function does not have any `return` keyword. By default, JS will interpret this as `undefined`, i.e. a non-truthy/false value. Therefore, all of your items fail to match the filter condition and you are left with an empty array.

Also, as pointed by others, you are missing a parenthesis.

```
let filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => {
    return item.title != title || item.body != body;
});
```

Comment: WoW :D, i am actually very surprised by the very fast response from all of you :) 
thanks very much and your answers indeed solved the problem, much appreciation ;) CHEERS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter in cases where *either* the body *or* the title does *not* match you actually need to use `&&` in you boolean.

For example if your `title` is "title 1" and your `body` is "body of title two", the only item it should return is `title 3` because that's the only one where *neither* the title nor body match.

And naturally you need to return this result from your filter callback, so either remove the `{}` around the function body or explicitly return the value.

```js
const removeItem = (title, body) => {
  let myArray = [
    {title : 'title 1', body: 'body of title one'},
    {title : 'title 2', body: 'body of title two'},
    {title : 'title 3', body: 'body of title three'}
  ]
  
  let filteredArray = myArray.filter((item) =>
    item.title != title 
    && item.body != body
  );
  return filteredArray  
}

 console.log(removeItem( // should only return title 3
  "title 1",
  "body of title two"
 ));

 console.log(removeItem( //should return title 2 and title 3
  "title 1",
  "body of title one"
 ));
```